# Ubuntu 13.10 boots to terminal (tty1) first?

Tags: login, 13.10

When I boot Ubuntu on my desktop it first brings me to the tty1 login screen once I login I get the normal graphical login and can login normally. Is there any way I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10. The computer would boot into tty1, waited around 30 seconds, and then would resume normal Ubuntu login screen into lightdm / graphical.

Thanks to an Ubuntu Forums' user (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182699) the solution for both of us was to remove the installed HP printer and also the "hplip" package. After a reboot, one could add the printer back, via System Settings>Printers>Add.

Boot is back to normal: a quick flash of tty1 login and then comes the prompt for normal Ubuntu login.

HTH